# Vuetify inside symfony project

Tags: symfony, webpack, vue.js, vuetify.js

I cannot find anything which would be helpful ( probably becouse I am not experienced web developer ) about setting up `Vuetify` with `Symfony` project. I am missing a `css-loader` and cannot figure out how it should be set.

[image]

```
// webpack.config.js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');

Encore
    // the project directory where all compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')

    // the public path used by the web server to access the previous directory
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    // will create public/build/app.js and public/build/app.css
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')

    // allow legacy applications to use $/jQuery as a global variable
    .autoProvidejQuery()

    // enable source maps during development
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())

    // empty the outputPath dir before each build
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()

    // show OS notifications when builds finish/fail
    .enableBuildNotifications()

    .addPlugin(new VueLoaderPlugin())

    .enableVueLoader()

    // create hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    // .enableVersioning()

    // allow sass/scss files to be processed
    .enableSassLoader()
;

// export the final configuration
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

It's pretty basic **webpack.congi.js**

**app.js**

```
import '@babel/polyfill'
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './components/App.vue'
import router from './router'

import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    components: { App },
    template: '<App/>'
});
```

I found how to set the `webpack` with `vuetify` but I am feeling that it's not for symfony project tho. [webpack + css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader)

Any ideas how could I set it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to do this with [Vuetify v2.x](https://vuetifyjs.com), rather than loading the styles from an external CDN (see [yerpy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51281503/296725)), you can load them via webpack as well. Assuming you've already created your Symfony project, first, make sure [symfony encore](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore) is installed:

```sh
$ composer require encore
```

Then install dependencies Vue and Vuetify:

```sh
$ npm i -S vue vuetify
```

Then install dev dependencies:

```sh
$ npm i -D vue-loader vuetify-loader vue-template-compiler sass sass-loader fibers
```

Then in `webpack.config.js` you'll want to import `vuetify-loader` at the top of the file and configure Encore as follows:

```js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin')

if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .enableVueLoader() // <-- IMPORTANT: this loads Vue
    // NOTE: I put my Vue app in assets/vue which I think is non-standard
    //       but it allows me to structure my Vue app as I would in a non-Symfony app
    .addEntry('app', './assets/vue/main.js')
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .configureBabel(() => {}, {
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        corejs: 3
    })
    // add VuetifyLoaderPlugin: THIS loads all of the Vuetify components
    .addPlugin(new VuetifyLoaderPlugin())
    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader(options => {
        options.implementation = require('sass')
        options.fiber = require('fibers')
    })
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Caveat, I am not a Symfony developer so I can't say this is the "best" way to do this. [Here's a repo with a working example](https://github.com/morphatic/symfony-vuetify-example) in case you need to see other files/configuration necessary to get all these things to play nice together.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are struggling / were struggling with the same issue the solution is pretty simple but not so obvious.

Inside **base.html.twig** or what ever is your `twig` file it has to be included:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}
```

Otherwise symfony will not be able to load css'sys

Comment: This works but don't forget to use 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
for icons and fonts.

Answer (score 0):

My setup looks like this:

- Install encore, follow the instructions at https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html
- I use yarn, so yarn install to install dependancies
- install vuetify - yarn add vuetify
- include vuetify in your application js entry point
- include vuetify stylesheet as well (like you did)
- most importantly you should require your main css/scss or whatever you use. In my case I have require(path to css)..this way, your css plus vuetify css will be compiled together